# How to fix position of Textview in RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am having this problem where I want to fix the position of my layout. I want to fix it in the center of my layout but every time I click on `EditText` which makes a keyboard pop up, the `TextView` shifts up and I don't want that to happen. Here is my code:

comment.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:flatui="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/comments_coordinator_layout">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/comments_appbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/layout_comments">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/send_message"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <com.cengalabs.flatui.views.FlatEditText
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:id="@+id/write_comment"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="5"
                    android:paddingTop="6dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    flatui:fl_theme="@array/color_primary_theme"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:cursorVisible="false"
                    android:hint="Comment back!"
                    android:background="@color/feed_bg"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    flatui:fl_fieldStyle="fl_box"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="false" />

                <com.cengalabs.flatui.views.FlatButton
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:id="@+id/send_comment"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Send"
                    flatui:fl_theme="@array/color_primary_theme"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    flatui:fl_textAppearance="fl_light"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@id/send_message"
                android:id="@+id/view_comments">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/no_comments_text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:text="No comments to display." />
        </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comments.java:

```
public class Comments extends AppCompatActivity {

    Post post;
    private CommentsDataSource commentsDatasource;
    //Local Database for storing posts
    private PostsDataSource postsDataSource;
    private FireBaseApplication application;
    private List<Comment> commentItems;
    private CommentsRecyclerViewAdapter commentsRecyclerViewAdapter;
    private RecyclerView commentsView;
    private TextView noCommentsView;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private LinearLayoutManager llm;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private boolean isNotificationActive;
    private String postId;
    private String tab;
    private String userId;
    private String posterUserId;
    private String posterName;
    private String postTimeStamp;
    private String postStatus;
    //Progress overlay
    View progressOverlay;
    DatabaseQuery databaseQuery;
    String name;

    private Firebase firebaseRef = new Firebase("https://tabsapp.firebaseio.com/");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.comments);
        setupActionBar();
        setupActivity(savedInstanceState);

        final EditText comment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.write_comment);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

        //Once we send the post, we want to
        comment.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                                          KeyEvent event) {
                comment.setCursorVisible(false);
                if (event != null && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    comment.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
                    in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(comment.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        //Hide the cursor until view is clicked on
        View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Touched");
                if (v.getId() == comment.getId()) {
                    comment.setCursorVisible(true);
                }
                commentsView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        commentsView.smoothScrollToPosition(commentsView.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1);
                    }
                }, 250);
                return false;
            }
        };
        comment.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener);

        //Button for sending post
        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_comment);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(comment.getText())) {
                    Toast.makeText(Comments.this, "Please enter in a comment first.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    String text = comment.getText().toString();
                    Comment createdComment = new Comment("", postId, name, text, userId, getDateTime());
                    Toast.makeText(Comments.this, "Successfully commented.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    comment.setText("");
                    InputMethodManager in = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                    in.hideSoftInputFromWindow(comment.getApplicationWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
                    comment.setCursorVisible(false);
                    updatePost();
                    databaseQuery.saveCommentToFirebase(createdComment);
                    saveCommentInCloud(createdComment, tab);
                    if (noCommentsView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        noCommentsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    //Notify friends that user has posted a comment on their post. Don't get notification if you posted on your own post.
//                    if(!createdComment.getCommenterUserId().equals(userId)) {
//                        showNotification(v, commenter);
//                    }

                }

            }
        });
        //Now we have to show a loading bar so that we are loading the comments. While we are loading the comments, we update the comments header
        populateCommentView(postId);
    }

    public void populateCommentView(String postId) {
        commentItems = new ArrayList<Comment>();
        getComments(postId);
    }

    private void setupActionBar() {
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.comments_appbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //Back bar enabled
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                //What happens if you click back
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    public void updatePost(){
        commentsView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                commentsView.smoothScrollToPosition(commentsView.getAdapter().getItemCount());
                //getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    private void checkAdapterIsEmpty () {
        if(application.getCommentsRecyclerViewAdapter().getItemCount() == 1){
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) noCommentsView.getLayoutParams();
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.view_post);
            noCommentsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else {
            noCommentsView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    public CommentsHeader getCommentsHeader(String id)
    {
        System.out.println("Going to inflate header");
        CommentsHeader header = new CommentsHeader();
        header.setPosterUserId(posterUserId);
        header.setPosterName(posterName);
        header.setPosterDate(postTimeStamp);
        header.setViewStatus(postStatus);
        return header;
    }


    public void populatePost(String id) {
        TextView statusMsg = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.view_status);
        System.out.println("Post: " + post);
        statusMsg.setText(post.getStatus());

        //Set profile picture
        DraweeController controller = news_feed.getImage(userId);
        SimpleDraweeView draweeView = (SimpleDraweeView) findViewById(R.id.poster_picture);
        draweeView.setController(controller);

        //Set poster's name
        TextView posterName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.poster_name);
        posterName.setText(post.getName());

        //Set date of when post was created
        TextView postDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.post_date);
        postDate.setText(AndroidUtils.convertDate(post.getTimeStamp()));
    }

    public String getIntentString(String value){
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String result = "";
        if (extras != null) {
            result = extras.getString(value);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Save the user's current game state
        savedInstanceState.putString("postId", postId);
        savedInstanceState.putString("tab", tab);
        savedInstanceState.putString("userId", userId);
        savedInstanceState.putString("name", name);
        savedInstanceState.putString("posterUserId", posterUserId);
        savedInstanceState.putString("posterName", posterName);
        savedInstanceState.putString("postTimeStamp", postTimeStamp);
        savedInstanceState.putString("postStatus", postStatus);
        // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void setupActivity(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore value of members from saved state
            if(savedInstanceState.containsKey("tab")) {
                tab = savedInstanceState.getString("tab");
            }
            if(savedInstanceState.containsKey("postId")) {
                postId = savedInstanceState.getString("postId");
            }
            if(savedInstanceState.containsKey("userId")) {
                userId = savedInstanceState.getString("userId");
            }
            if(savedInstanceState.containsKey("name")) {
                name = savedInstanceState.getString("name");
            }
            if(savedInstanceState.containsKey("posterUserId")) {
                posterUserId = savedInstanceState.getString("posterUserId");
            }
            if(savedInstanceState.containsKey("posterName")) {
                posterName = savedInstanceState.getString("posterName");
            }
            if(savedInstanceState.containsKey("postTimeStamp")) {
                postTimeStamp = savedInstanceState.getString("postTimeStamp");
            }
            if(savedInstanceState.containsKey("postStatus")) {
                postStatus = savedInstanceState.getString("postStatus");
            }
        } else {
            postId = getIntentString("postId");
            tab = getIntentString("tab");
            userId = getIntentString("userId");
            posterUserId = getIntentString("posterUserId");
            posterName = getIntentString("posterName");
            postTimeStamp = getIntentString("postTimeStamp");
            postStatus = getIntentString("postStatus");
            // Probably initialize members with default values for a new instance
        }

        databaseQuery = new DatabaseQuery(this);
        application = ((FireBaseApplication) getApplication());
        progressOverlay = findViewById(R.id.progress_overlay);
        if(application.getName() != null && application.getName() != "") {
            name = application.getName();
        } else {
            if(savedInstanceState != null) {
                if(savedInstanceState.containsKey("name")) {
                    name = savedInstanceState.getString("name");
                }
            }
        }
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.comments_appbar);
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        commentsView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.view_comments);
        noCommentsView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no_comments_text);
        llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        commentsView.setLayoutManager(llm);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".com.tabs.activity.Comments"
        android:label="View Post"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustPan"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".com.tabs.activity.Comments"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />

    </activity>
```

I have tried to set my `TextView` to `android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"` or have tried to set `android:centerVertical="true"` but the former produces the same exact behavior and the latter makes my `TextView` not even show up. Is there any way I can fix the position of the `TextView`? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: does the problem persist when you change coordinatorLayout to LinearLayout? I got a hunch that the problem can be isolated to that.

Answer (score 1):

Add **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"** in **activity** tag on Manifest.xml

Comment: I just tried that but the behavior is the same unfortunately.

Comment: I have added `       getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);` in my .java file because I wouldn't want `adjustPan` since that would shift the focus to the keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I think `configChanges` flag shall be added to your manifest file ,to solve this

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

For more details read this post from developer's website

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Answer (score 0):

You should read about the `android:windowSoftInputMode` property that you can add to your Activity in AndroidManifest.xml. You can read about it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft

You have plenty of options there, choose the one that fits your needs.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I have looked through it and I have added        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN); into my code which is what I want but if i try `adjustPan` that is not what I want since that would shift the focus to my keyboard/edit text which isn't what I want. Any other ideas?

Comment: The TextView actually stays centered, but SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE is changing the height of the screen so, naturally, the center moves up and your TextView with it. SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_NOTHING is what I think you would like, but you might have an EditText at the bottom of the screen and the keyboard might hide it. You could also try to set the TextView centered in the screen, get its position and set that position as fixed in the screen by using marginTop or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

`android:layout_centerInParent="true"` for your `TextView`, and use `android:layout_above="@+id/view_comments"`?

Untested, but `TextView` needs some layout parameters that relates to `RelativeLayout`.